# Is there a template specific for post_type-term combo?

Tags: wordpress, hook, custom-post-type, permalinks, custom-taxonomy

Just trying to verify this, there is no specific template file for a post_type-term combo right? I'm not sure how to go about my setup where I have created 2 CPTs(**CPT_1** & **CPT_2**) and 1 shared custom taxonomy (**CT-1**) between the CPTs.

I wanted to generate the following permalinks:

```
[1] domain.com/cpt_1/parent_term1/post_1_in_cpt_1/ [post specific under cpt_1]
[2] domain.com/cpt_2/parent_term1/post_1_in_cpt_2/ [post specific under cpt_2]

[3][x] domain.com/cpt_1/parent_term1 [archive for post under *parent_term1 in *CPT_1]
[4][x] domain.com/cpt_2/parent_term1 [archive for post under *parent_term1 in *CPT_2]

[5] domain.com/cpt_1 [archive for all post in CPT_1]
[6] domain.com/cpt_2 [archive for all post in CPT_2]

[7] domain.com/ct/parent_term1 [archive for all the posts from the 2 CPTs that share the term]
```

so far I was able to properly get the correct permalinks except 3 & 4 because when I visit either `domain.com/cpt_1/parent_term1/` or `domain.com/cpt_2/parent_term1/` it just gives me to page for `domain.com/ct/parent_term1/` which is the archive page for the term parent_term1 under ct-1 taxonomy. Is there a way I could create an archive page for specific term under a custom post type?

Update 1:
Currently, here is my config:

**`CPT_1`**

```
'has_archive' => 'cpt_1',
'taxonomies' => array('ct-1'),
$rewrite = array(
    'slug' => 'cpt_1/%ct-1%',
     ...
);
```

**`CPT_2`**

```
'has_archive' => 'cpt_2',
'taxonomies' => array('ct-1'),
$rewrite = array(
    'slug' => 'cpt_2/%ct-1%',
     ...
);
```

while my custom taxonomy [**ct-1**] has:

```
,'has_archive' => true
,"rewrite" => array(
            "slug" => 'ct'
        )
```

im updating the links for each post in the cpt_* via this code

```
add_filter('post_type_link', 'update_permalink_structure', 10, 2);
function update_permalink_structure( $post_link, $post )
{
    if ( false !== strpos( $post_link, '%ct-1%' ) ) {
        $taxonomy_terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'ct-1' );
        foreach ( $taxonomy_terms as $term ) { 
            if ( ! $term->parent ) {
                $post_link = str_replace( '%ct-1%', $term->slug, $post_link );
            }
        } 
    }
    return $post_link;
}
```

my problem permalinks are:

```
[3][x] domain.com/cpt_1/parent_term1
[4][x] domain.com/cpt_2/parent_term1
```

where in each item I would like to use the corresponding `cpt_*` archive and grab the `parent_term*` to limit/filter out the post in the archive to include only those post under the said term. however, in my current setup visiting either links just resolves same as visiting `[7] domain.com/ct/parent_term1`

Comment: This might help you out: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/275825/display-custom-post-type-taxonomies-as-an-archive-page

Comment: thanks @JamesHamann but unfortunately its not working for me i have updated my question to give more info.